# Can I use Config Vars in templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a Rails app deployed on Heroku.

If I set the following var `PRODUCTION_ENV: true`, is it possible to check for it in code, i.e.

```
<% PRODUCTION_ENV == true %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check environment variables using `ENV`, so you would check `ENV['PRODUCTION_ENV']`. However, if you're just checking if you're using the production environment it would be better to use `Rails.env.production?` instead.